# Who was the last/is the current count of Orsay?

Tags: france, nobility, genealogy

[Alfred d'Orsay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_d%27Orsay) (1801-1852), comte d'Orsay, had no children so I believed that the title passed to his sister Ida d'Orsay (who is mentioned to be countess of Orsay on various websites) and then to her <s>eldest son Agénor de Gramont (1819-1880) (10th duke of Gramont)</s> only still living child Antonia Gabrielle Léontine.

[image: Orsay]

However, there are two issues here:

- <s>Agénor</s> Antonia never used the title "compte d'Orsay" as far as I know,
- the title was never claimed again.

So who was the last count of Orsay, and who is the last person we have trace of who could claim it?

Comment: Let's have some dates, please.  And some indication of why this is an interesting question, if possible.

Comment: I added some dates, I didn't quite understand the second part of your comment, it's just a question I'm asking myself

Comment: I am asking, why this is a history question, and not just some random genealogy query.

Comment: I mean genealogy of nobility can be considered as history, I have found similar well-recieved question on the site [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/51487/what-present-day-monarchs-descend-from-rodrigo-de-borgia-a-k-a-pope-alexander), or [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/57410/is-carolyn-seymour-the-actress-related-to-alexander-von-benckendorff-the-russ).

Comment: This seems to assume the title can be inherited down the female line - do we know that to be true? My (not very detailed) understanding is that most French titles were male-line only.

Comment: Note that titles were [abolished in France in 1848](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_nobility#Nobility_since_the_Revolution) and reinstated in the year of Alfred's death, 1852. Perhaps timing is the issue here. Some parts of the [Constitution of 1852](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Constitution_of_1852) were not completed until Dec 2 and 25th of 1852, so its possible there was no legal form established at the time for the transference of the title, until after Alfred had passed in August.

Comment: French nobility is transmitted through male primogeniture but not through male-only descendance as far as I know. I will investigate the legal point, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The last countess of Orsay was *Antonia Gabrielle Léontine de Gramont*, daughter of Ida d'Orsay and grand-daughter of Jean François Louis Marie Albert Gaspard Grimod, the third count of Orsay.

Indeed, when Ida d'Orsay died in 1882, her only still-living child was  Antonia Gabrielle Léontine de Gramont who left no descendance.

Moreover, Ida d'Orsay and Alfred Guillaume Gabriel Grimod d'Orsay were the only children of the only child of Pierre Gaspard Marie Grimod d'Orsay who was himself the only child of the first count of Orsay.

[image: orsay]

As a consequence, as far as I understand, the maison d'Orsay has died out.

**Edit.** Crucially, Alfred was the only surviving child of the third count (apart from Ida) and had no descendance.